# This certain MySQL database organisation

Tags: mysql, database-design

Hypothetically, let's say that I have three tables:

```
- Products (id, product_name, added_timestamp)
- Individuals (id, name, last_name)
- Companies (id, company_name, company_number, company_address)
```

Now, let's say that both individuals and companies can add their products to my virtual shop.

Now, let's say I want to display all the added products sorted from descending order by the `Products.added_timestamp` column. However, I don't know how to connect Products with Individuals and Companies and display all the data.

How would I approach this problem?

Comment: Use JOINs, Luke.

Comment: *edit cuz reading is hard*  Put references to the individual/company in the products table.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than the obvious which is to create a table with a key to the product id and another to the individual or company ids?

Comment: use the Party Model with Table Inheritance. http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/advanceddm.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least 2 ways of doing this.

1. Add nullable `individual_id` and `company_id` FK columns to `Products` table.

   When products are added by an individual, populate the `individual_id`. When products are added by a company, populate the `company_id`. This would be a many-to-one relationship between products-and-individuals or products-and-companies.

   Sample query would be something like:

   ```
   select p.product_name, p.added_timestamp, i.name as 'individual_name', c.company_name as 'company_name'
   from Products p
   left outer join Individuals i on p.individual_id = i.id
   left outer join Companies c on p.company_id = c.id
   order by p.added_timestamp desc
   ```
2. Create separate mapping tables, e.g. `Products_By_Individuals` and `Products_By_Companies`, to associate products with individuals and companies externally. This would be a many-to-many relationship between products-and-individuals or products-and-companies.

   Sample schema:

   - Products_By_Individuals (id, product_id, individual_id)
   - Products_By_Companies (id, product_id, company_id)

   And sample queries:

   ```
   select p.product_name, p.added_timestamp, i.name as 'entity_name'
   from Products_By_Individuals pbi
   inner join Products p on pbi.product_id = p.id
   inner join Individuals i on pbi.individual_id = i.id
   union
   select p.product_name, p.added_timestamp, c.company_name as 'entity_name'
   from Products_By_Companies pbc
   inner join Products p on pbc.product_id = p.id
   inner join Companies c on pbc.company_id = c.id
   order by p.added_timestamp desc
   ```

   If you play with the projections (the select clause), you could possibly due a `union` between these 2 queries.

EDIT: modified sample queries to return (1) product name, (2) product timestamp, and (3) individual or company name, as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Thanks superEb, this is more what I was looking for but still...

Comment: Alright, I will rephrase the question a little bit:

An individual "Kate" added a product at 8 am called "Teddybear"
A company "SuperCompany" added a product at 9 am called "Laptop"
An individual "John" added a product at 10 am called "Lollypop"

Now I want to display something like:

Products:
1. Lollypop - by Kate (individual) at 10 am
2. Laptop - by SuperCompany (company) at 9 am
3. Teddybear - by Kate (individual) at 8 am

How do I do this?

Comment: Plus I have to keep in mind that there might be a lot of groups of users with diffirent types of data that can add their products, so the "individual_id", "company_id" might be too much of a killer for the project.

Comment: You're gonna need a way to relate the entities, unless you duplicate data somewhere (as one might do with a NoSQL database), so I'm not sure what your concern with `individual_id` and `company_id` is. With #1 from my answer, you can do exactly what you want, just change `select *` to select the columns/values that you need (e.g. product name, added timestamp, individual name, and company name). Then have your UI use individual name if it returns a non-null value; otherwise use company name.

Comment: Let's clear it up. You're telling me to pack all the tables in one row? Like product_id|product_name|ind_id|ind_name|ind_last_name|comp_id|comp_name? And then just display corresponding columns depending on if they're not null? I was thinking about this in the beginning but wasn't sure if it was a good solution because it might generate like 100 columns in one result quesry for example.

Comment: If by "pack all the tables in one row", you mean fetching data from multiple tables in your queries, so that "all tables" get packed into the result set, then yes. If you mean flattening the data model into a single table, then no. I edited the queries in my answer. Does that help clear things up?

Comment: Generalizing... is it a good idea to put many columns in one query result even if I know that most of them are going to be null because for example none of the individual and companies added a product but a corporation did. So for product_id|product_name|ind_id|ind_name|comp_id|comp_number|corp_id|corp_address it'll generate something like: 1|"Doll"|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|50|"Chupacabra Street 17". I just want you to confirm if it's the best solution in this situation please :)

Comment: The "best" solution obviously depends on the circumstances and goals - expected number of records, query execution plan, acceptable query performance, likelihood of reuse, etc. Is it the best? Depends on your requirements. Is it viable? Certainly. In general, if you can get away with a single query, then you probably should, unless the query performance is terrible. But there are even ways around that. For instance, if you expect a large number of rows in the result set, then perhaps you should use paging and fetch the data one page-at-a-time. There's also stored procedures, indexes, etc.

Comment: If you don't mind, I would appreciate an up-vote. Thanks.

Comment: How do I vote a comment?

Comment: Oh sorry, it needs 15 reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this by creating the relevant foreign keys so you can use relations in your databases.
[Here is a nice read](http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/fundamentalsofrelationaldatabasedesign.aspx) about relational databases.
I strongly recommend it for you to read it, sou you can get the hang of the relational design idea.

Edit:
In your particular case i would to this:

- Products (id, product_name, added_timestamp, seller_type, seller_id)
- Individuals (id, name, last_name)
- Companies (id, company_name, company_number, company_address)

where seller_type can be either 'i' as Individual or 'c' Company, and seller_id is the corresponding foreign id.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it... I can put a column `adder` to Products and relate it to only one other table. How does this relate to my problem?